# Azure Pipeline to Pipeline trigger using YAML (Skip)

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a variable called validate in the first pipeline and if it is set to true skip the trigger of the second pipeline .

The yaml sample pipeline

```
trigger: none // add this trigger value to none 
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: RELEASE_PIPELINE // any arbitrary name
    source: PIPELINE_NAME.    // name of the pipeline shown on azure UI portal
    trigger:
    branches:
      include:
        - dummy_branch
```

I have a variable(as global) set on the pipeline called **validate** as true/false.

The second pipeline should not be triggered if its set to True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement can not be achieved using variable in a triggering pipeline. Instead of using triggering pipeline, you could use a task to queue the second pipeline and condition whether the task would run. For example:

```
parameters:
- name: 'validateTrigger'
  type: boolean
  default: false

steps:
- task: #first pipeline tasks
- ${{ if eq(parameters.validateTrigger, true) }}:
  - script: #queue second pipeline
```